# GLUT problem with the support of hidpi retina on macOS (c++)

Tags: c++, macos, glut, retina, hidpi

I making a port of my 3d program to macOS.
I'm using c++ and FreeGlut at windows. So at macOS, I've started to use it with GLUT. I don't use cocoa and create an OpenGL window context via GLUT.
There is a problem with the support of hidpi retina.
Glut reshapefunc is detecting two times the smaller resolution (I mean it detects logical points, not actual retina pixels) That's why the image looks pixelated.
How to turn on retina support in GLUT (or freeglut)?
I've tried the solution from this article http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/glut-macosx/ (add line "hidpi" to glutInitDisplayString
and GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE to glutInitDisplayMode). But it doesn't help.
Is it possible to make it without big changes in the program? Because it's quite a big program (3d software).
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one of glutInitDisplayString and glutInitDisplayMode.
glutInitDisplayMode overides glutInitDisplayString if it comes after.

try:

glutInitDisplayString("hidpi core rgba double")